# Why gridview reload images in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview

I'm trying to use show images using by `Image.file(File(path))` in gridview. When I scrolling it down and then up it's reloading images. This caused showing them in white. When I'm looking for this issue there is mentions "lazy loading list" but I don't think it's related with this. Also I tried caching Image widget with LruCache but it's still same. How can I prevent this reloading?

Here is my code snippet:

```
  child: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: paths.length,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          childAspectRatio: 0.5,
          crossAxisSpacing: 6,
          mainAxisSpacing: 6,
          crossAxisCount: 5,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => {remove(paths[index])},
            child: Image.file(File(paths[index])),
          );
        },
      ),
```

This is an error: **stop reason = EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY flutter**

Answer (score 2):

```
GridView(gridDelegate: gridDelegate, cacheExtent: 9999,)
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried this. When I do it like that app crashes.

Comment: Why crash? does it return any errors? Maybe show us some code so we know where the problem is. Try cacheExtent 100 or 200

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I added my code snippet and also the error.

Comment: Yeah that error means that your app is using too many resources, maybe the number I gave you was a bit exaggerated try cacheExtent: 1000 or even 100

Comment: I put cacheExtent: 1000 but still throws error.

Answer (score 0):

Use these attributes in `CachedNetworkImage`

```
memCacheHeight: 128,
memCacheWidth: 128,
```

Numbers depends on image size.